# Multiple columns from DUAL?

Tags: sql, oracle, dual-table

I'm using Oracle 12c.
I need to generate dates for the start and end of weeks which begin on Thursday and end the following Wednesday.
An example of the output I'd like is -

[image]

I have the following SQL to generate the Start Date(s) -

```
SELECT startdate
  FROM (SELECT next_day(date '2020-03-12' - 1, 'Thursday') + (level - 1) * 7 AS startdate
          FROM dual
       CONNECT BY level <=
                   ((date'2024-03-31' - next_day(date '2020-03-12' - 1, 'Wednesday') + 7) / 7))
```

and this for End Dates -

```
(SELECT enddate
   FROM (SELECT next_day(date '2020-03-12' - 1, 'Wednesday') + (level - 1) * 7 as enddate
           FROM dual
         CONNECT BY level <= ((date'2024-03-31' - next_day(date'2020-03-12' - 1, 'Thursday') + 7) / 7)))
```

Is it even possible to combine these in a single SQL query so the output of the query matches the desired format?

If so, then the addition of the week number would also be rather nice...:)

Comment: Use a single row generator (`connect by`) to generate the required number of rows and then calculate the date you need in the `select` list as you currently do, but as separate expressions (columns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate the start date and then add 6 days to get the end date:

```sql
SELECT startdate,
       startdate + INTERVAL '6' DAY AS enddate,
       week
FROM   (
  SELECT NEXT_DAY(date'2020-03-12' - 1, 'Thursday')
           + ( level - 1 ) * INTERVAL '7' DAY as startdate,
         LEVEL AS week
  FROM   DUAL
  CONNECT BY
         NEXT_DAY(date'2020-03-12' - 1, 'Thursday')
           + ( level - 1 ) * INTERVAL '7' DAY
           + INTERVAL '6' DAY
           <= date'2024-03-31'
)
```

Which outputs:

> | STARTDATE | ENDDATE | WEEK |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2020-03-12 00:00:00 | 2020-03-18 00:00:00 | 1 |
> | 2020-03-19 00:00:00 | 2020-03-25 00:00:00 | 2 |
> | 2020-03-26 00:00:00 | 2020-04-01 00:00:00 | 3 |
> | ... | ... | ... |
> | 2024-03-07 00:00:00 | 2024-03-13 00:00:00 | 209 |
> | 2024-03-14 00:00:00 | 2024-03-20 00:00:00 | 210 |
> | 2024-03-21 00:00:00 | 2024-03-27 00:00:00 | 211 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=3a9abec238f17ab6c8af20d384c95ecd)*